keyboard: The input method is developed and added to the list of available keyboards when scrolling highlighted like in the video
The input method is developed and added to the list of available keyboards when scrolling highlighted like in the video, This is my code
 val startSettings = Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
        }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        startActivity(startSettings)

About return, I am currently starting a timing thread, cyclic detection of whether the keyboard is allowed, to start the corresponding Activity, but because it is the background, in the high version of the system will be directly prohibited, gods, come on
